# How do I sync my vimfiles with Dropbox or other cloud storage?

Tags: vimrc, startup

I followed the directions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184897/13287828) to sync my `vimrc` file in Dropbox with my two Windows computers. However, I also want to move all the other user content of my `vimfiles` folder to Dropbox as suggested by jqno. I've read the documentation on Vim's initialization steps and environment variables, but can't figure out a way to direct it to my plugin folders, syntax files, color schemes, etc. in Dropbox.

This is my current `vimrc`:

```
let $MYVIMRC = "C:/Users/Norbert/Dropbox/vimfiles/vimrc"
set runtimepath^=$HOME/Dropbox/vimfiles
source $HOME\Dropbox\vimfiles\vimrc
```

If I copy all the contents of `vimfiles` to Dropbox and remove them from my $HOME directory, leaving only this minimal `vimrc`, none of my plugins load. If all the files are in their normal location, with only the full `vimrc` in Dropbox, everything works.

I've thought of two directions to go with this:

1. Have only one `vimfiles` location with full content, located in Dropbox. Find some way to direct Vim to these files by either a relative or absolute path.
2. Have a `vimfiles` location in Documents or another directory Dropbox can push to, so that each machine receives changes. However, I would still have to move the files on each machine and tell Vim where to look for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is by having all the vim files located in my dropbox directory and then creating symlinks for the `vimrc` and `vimfiles` directory in my home directory.  That way, vim isn't even aware that I'm doing anything "non-standard"; it just looks where it normally would and it finds the files as expected.

It's been a a few years since I've had to do this on Windows, but the [`mklink`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) utility is what you should need to create the symlinks.

Edit: You can save a symlink by placing your `vimrc` in the `vimfiles` directory.  Checkout `:help vimrc` for more info.

Comment: Can you keep your vimrc in vimfiles on windows? On nix I can have my vimrc be ~/.vim/vimrc, so it’s just one symlink

Comment: I can't believe I never bothered to look into this.  It has always annoyed me that I've had to have two symlinks.  According to `:help vimrc` it should work in Windows as well by placing the file at `$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc`.

Comment: I'll try this out, it seems like an easy solution. I can confirm that by default, the vimrc is in the vimfiles directory on Windows, so I'll only need one symlink. Does this method mean that the `runtimepath` does not need to be modified?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  You shouldn't need any special configuration to tell vim where to find stuff with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about setting up a Git repository with `vimfiles`?

Also, `$MYVIMRC` is a Enviorment Variable that you must set in you system, not on your `vimrc`, since Vim will go to that folder to locate the `vimrc` file.

Comment: Git is a steep learning curve for a non-programmer like me, so I'd like a Dropbox solution. I only set the $MYVIMRC for internal use in Vim, as the documentation suggested. I know it's not really necessary, but I wanted to save a step in getting to my full vimrc if I type it in the GVim command line.